# In Rails are these Time difference command producing excepted bheviour? If so why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, activesupport

#### Steps to reproduce

Is this a excepted behaviour?

1. Open the rails console.
2. Type the following command:

```rb
Time.zone.yesterday - Time.zone.now
```

Output:

```
/Users/manishsharma/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activesupport-7.0.3.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/date/calculations.rb:104:in `-': expected numeric (TypeError)
```

```rb
Time.zone.now - Time.zone.yesterday
```

Output:

```
3.1.2 :002 > Time.zone.now - Time.zone.yesterday
/Users/manishsharma/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activesupport-7.0.3.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/calculations.rb:209:in `ago': undefined method `-@' for Wed, 21 Sep 2022:Date (NoMethodError)

    since(-seconds)
          ^
Did you mean?  -
/Users/manishsharma/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activesupport-7.0.3.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/calculations.rb:294:in `-': can't convert Date into an exact number (TypeError)
```

```rb
Time.zone.now - Time.zone.yesterday
```

Output:

```
/Users/manishsharma/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activesupport-7.0.3.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/date/calculations.rb:104:in `-': expected numeric (TypeError)
```

```rb
3.1.2 :003 > Time.zone.now - Date.yesterday
```

```
/Users/manishsharma/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activesupport-7.0.3.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/calculations.rb:209:in `ago': undefined method `-@' for Wed, 21 Sep 2022:Date (NoMethodError)

    since(-seconds)
          ^
Did you mean?  -
/Users/manishsharma/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activesupport-7.0.3.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/calculations.rb:294:in `-': can't convert Date into an exact number (TypeError)
```

#### System configuration

**Rails version**: 7.0.3.1

**Ruby version**: 3.1.2

Comment: If this is a bug you may want to report it instead. Did it work in older versions of Rails and/or Ruby? Is `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone#-` valid with `Date`?

Comment: What is the goal here? Calculating how much time has elapsed since the `beginning_of_day`? If so: `Time.zone.now - Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day`.

Comment: _"Is this a excepted behaviour?"_ – that's basically a yes / no question and I assume "yes, that error is expected" won't help you much. It would be more valuable if you could explain _your_ expectation so we can provide a solution to your problem. What are you trying to do and what is the expected result?

Answer (score 1):

`Time.zone.yesterday` or `Time.zone.today` returns date whereas `Time.zone.now` returns a timestamp. And you can't calculate diff between a date and a timestamp. The errors you are getting are expected.